# How can I use Paypal for future payments without redirects?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-rest-sdk

In my web app (PHP) the user should be able to connect his paypal account and every time he sold a product from our catalog we will charge him the price.
Since the user might sell lot of products I want to make the payment part automatically so he won't have to approve every transaction.

Unfortunately I don't find a way to do this with Paypal SDK.

Currently the app is using the OAuth flow so the user is redirected to Paypal from where I get the access_token for him.

Question: Having the access_token for an user how can I create a (background) payment without the Paypal redirect?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my question here since I think I found a solution.
It looks like this can be done using [Payment Preapproval Api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicPreapproval-curl-etc/)